# Browser Notifications with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, service-worker

Currently working on browser notifications and trying to keep endpoints in db, sometimes `registration.pushManager.subscribe` returns new one subscription and in that case service create new one endpoint, for avoid that I want to keep some uniq key for browser.
So..my question is how can I get uniq browser id at backend part in Rails app

Comment: That's not quite as easy as you would think. While you could for example use the IP that will give issues with clients on a network that changes IPs constantly. Your best bet may to be to go with using a cookie.

Comment: I've decided to use LocalStorage for keep uniq generic key :)